# Login function to recognize if user has set up Profile or not

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

So I have this following code for my LoginPage..

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { RegisterPage } from '../../pages/register/register';
import { HomePage } from '../../pages/home/home';
import { ProfileSetupPage } from '../../pages/profiles/profile-setup/profile-setup';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  user = {} as User;

  constructor(private afAuth : AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCon: AlertController) {

  }

  onGoToRegister(){
    this.navCtrl.push(RegisterPage);
  }

  showInvalidUserAlert(){
    let alert = this.alertCon.create({
      title: 'Invalid Login',
      subTitle: 'Sorry about that! Try logging in again',
      buttons: ['Got it']
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  async onLogin(user: User){
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
      .then(res => {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(ProfileSetupPage);
      }, err => {
        let msg;
        switch (err.code){
          case "auth/wrong-password":
            msg = "Email or Password is incorrect";
            break;
          case "auth/user-not-found":
            msg = "User not found"
            break;
          case "auth/invalid-email":
            msg = "Oops! Invalid email. Please try again"
            break;
        }
        alert(msg);
      });
  }

  onLogout(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }

}
```

My onLogin function takes in values from a User model, and then validates those credentials and if they are correct will re direct you to the ProfileSetupPage. This is the correct workflow if they are a new user and have yet to create their profile, however, if they are an existing user they should just be authenticated and be redirected to the HomePage. What is the best way to handle this? Should I just include another value in the User model that is a boolean and toggle it that way? Or maybe ionic/firebase has an easier solution. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

One simple way pf achieving you goal is to store a token in `localStorage` or `Native Storage` when a user first signs up, then check for this token when the app is opened. If the token exists, you can redirect the user using `NavController`

```
 import { RegisterPage } from '../../pages/register/register';
    import { HomePage } from '../../pages/home/home';
    import { ProfileSetupPage } from '../../pages/profiles/profile-setup/profile-setup';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
    export class LoginPage {

      user = {} as User;

      constructor(private afAuth : AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCon: AlertController) {
//Conditional Redirect On Constructor Call
if(window.localStorage.getItem('userExists')) navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);

      }

      onGoToRegister(){
        this.navCtrl.push(RegisterPage);
      }

      showInvalidUserAlert(){
        let alert = this.alertCon.create({
          title: 'Invalid Login',
          subTitle: 'Sorry about that! Try logging in again',
          buttons: ['Got it']
        });
        alert.present();
      }

      async onLogin(user: User){
          this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
          .then(res => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('userExists', JSON.stringify(res)};
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(ProfileSetupPage);

           }, err => {
            let msg;
            switch (err.code){
              case "auth/wrong-password":
                msg = "Email or Password is incorrect";
                break;
              case "auth/user-not-found":
                msg = "User not found"
                break;
              case "auth/invalid-email":
                msg = "Oops! Invalid email. Please try again"
                break;
            }
            alert(msg);
          });
      }

      onLogout(){
        this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
      }

    }
```

You need to make sure to remove the stored item from `LocalStorage` when user logs out otherwise they will continue to have access to the HomePage after logging out,

Comment: Okay let me give this a shot and see how it turns out.. I was hoping to store some sort of variable that would be attached to the user rather than the device because I am not sure how it would work out if they ever had multiple devices or changed phones or something like that.. Would that be cause for concern or something that may cause bugs down the road?